# Remote debugging error: Unable to attach to the process. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging

I have installed and run as administrator the Remote tools for Debugging on Windows 2012 R2.

I am trying to connect from Visual Studio 2019 to this server and debug a process.

The available processes show up when I connect to the server but when I select the one I need to debug Visual Studio shows an error message box:

**Unable to attach to the process. The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.**

Is there anything I can do to troubleshoot or otherwise fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite a delayed response but I was getting the exact same error.

What worked for me was starting Visual Studio in administrator mode (Run as Administrator) as well and then I was then able to attach to the process successfully.

Definitely restart your Visual Studio instance.